# How to incorporate "sweet alert" into a confirmation dialog on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, css

I have seen "sweet alerts" on github.
https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-sweetalert/
Essentially gives you these nice looking modal popups

[image]
[image]

But how do you tie that in to a "delete" function or "confirm" before submit" on SharePoint?

I am a novice coder at best hopefully a guru can help.

Comment: You can use client side rendering to add a custom delete button on the view and open the modal popup when the user clicks on the custom button. Upon confirming the deletion, use JSOM/REST to delete the item from the list. For information on CSR -  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: I you want to tie it to the out of the box SharePoint forms, search for 'PreSaveAction' and override that function to include your logic.

Comment: Hello Aveenav, I looked into it but don't see anything that helps me tie PreSaveAction with "Sweet Alert".